# stroke-opacity has no effect on svg:text while conveting svg to pdf using fop-2.2

Tags: css, svg, apache-fop

I am upgrading batik-1.7 to 1.11 and fop-0.94 to 2.2. I am using PDFTranscoder of fop to convert SVG to PDF in my application. stroke-opacity is applied to text in svg. Before upgrading pdf looks good and result is as expected with opacity. But after upgrading stroke-opacity is not being applied to text.

Below is the code used to convert svg to pdf:

```
Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgFile.toURI().toString());
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outStream);
transcoder.transcode(input, output);
```

svg file used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="418" viewBox="0,0 65416,45424" width="816" xml:space="preserve">   
<defs>
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
.P{
font-family:"Arial";
font-weight:normal;
font-size:247px;
font-family:"Lucida Sans";
font-style:normal;
stroke:#000;
stroke-width:16px;
stroke-dasharray:none;
stroke-linejoin:miter;
stroke-miterlimit:10;
stroke-width:0.5px;
stroke-linecap:square;
stroke-opacity:1.0;
fill:none;
fill-opacity:0.0;
fill-rule:evenodd;
}

.M{
font-family:"Arial";
font-weight:normal;
font-size:282px;
font-style:normal;
stroke:#00F;
stroke-dasharray:none;
stroke-linejoin:miter;
stroke-miterlimit:10;
stroke-width:2px;
stroke-linecap:square;
stroke-opacity:1.0;
fill:#00F;
fill-rule:evenodd;
fill-opacity:1.0;
}

.dimmed{
stroke-opacity:0.5;
fill-opacity:0.0;
}
]]></style>
</defs>
<g>


<g>

<path class="dimmed P" d="M7964,25320h5669m-5669,0v1905m0,-1401h5669m-5669,467h5669m-5669,467h5669m-5669,467h5669m-4968,-1401v1401m934,-1401v1401m785,-1401v1401m743,-1401v1401m1295,-1401v1401m1210,-1905v1905"/> 

<text class="dimmed M" x="10258" y="25695">CONN3</text>
<text class="M" x="8054" y="26172">Cav</text>
</g>
</g>

</svg>
```

Stroke-opacity in "dimmed" class is not showing any effect on the text "CONN3" after upgrading batik and fop.

Comment: If you want to report batik bugs you need to do so [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BATIK/issues)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/fop/blob/trunk/fop-core/src/main/java/org/apache/fop/svg/AbstractFOPTranscoder.java talk about new key to disable auto-font. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above error occured because stroke -opacity of text is assigned as "1" by default. So whatever the value we pass to stroke-oppacity attribute it does not have any effect.

I have solved the issue by modifying the "applyColorAndPaint" of PDFTextPainter.java in fop source code and rebuilt the jar.

```
private void applyColorAndPaint(TextPaintInfo tpi) { 
 Paint fillPaint = tpi.fillPaint; 
 Paint strokePaint = tpi.strokePaint; 
 Stroke stroke = tpi.strokeStroke; 
 int fillAlpha = PDFGraphics2D.OPAQUE; 
 int strokeAlpha = PDFGraphics2D.OPAQUE; 
 if (fillPaint instanceof Color) { 
      Color col = (Color) fillPaint; 
      pdf.applyColor(col, true); 
      fillAlpha = col.getAlpha(); 
 } 
 if (strokePaint instanceof Color) { 
      Color col = (Color) strokePaint; 
      pdf.applyColor(col, false); 
      strokeAlpha = col.getAlpha(); 
 } 
 pdf.applyPaint(fillPaint, true); 
 pdf.applyStroke(stroke); 

 if (strokePaint != null){ 
      pdf.applyPaint(strokePaint, false); 
 } 
 pdf.applyAlpha(fillAlpha, strokeAlpha); 
}
```